# Find coordinates with respect to the basis

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

My problem is that I have to find the coordinates for $\cos^2(x)$ and $\sin^2(x)$ with respect to the basis, which is $\left\{1,\cos(x), \sin(x), \cos(2x), \sin(2x)\right\}$ and I'm not exactly sure how to do this.

I know that I have to find the coefficients of $\cos^2(x) = a+b\cos(x)+c\sin(x)+d\cos(2x)+e\sin(2x)$ to get the coordinates for $\cos^2(x)$, but I'm not sure of the method or how to do that.

Every help will be appreciated, I feel like I just need a little push in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

Recall your double-angle formulas: $\cos(2x)=2\cos^2x-1$....

Comment: So would the coordinates for $cos^2(x)$ be ($\frac{1}{2}$,0,0,$\frac{1}{2}$,0)?

Comment: Precisely. And for $\sin^2x$, you can use yet another identity...

Comment: Thank you so much! This helps a lot!